# Authentication/Authorization w/ Warden (Server-side) + Backbone.js (Client-side)

Tags: javascript, authentication, backbone.js, authorization, warden

I'm struggling with implementing a proper front-end auth solution for my de-coupled setup. It consists of the following:

**Server-side** Ruby API (using Warden for email/password auth)

**Client-side** Backbone.js app

I think I'm stuck at how to properly pass tokens from the server to the client.

This passage from [staticapps.org](http://www.staticapps.org/articles/authentication-and-authorization) explains the type of flow I'm looking to achieve:

> 1. The client directs the user to a server-side authentication process. This may be a JavaScript pop-up window or a browser redirect triggered by setting window.location.
> 2. The server authenticates the identity of the user via password, social sign-in, or other means.
> 3. The server creates a randomly generated token and associates it with the now authenticated user.
> 4. The server transmits the token back to the client.
> 5. The client includes the provided token on subsequent requests to the server as a proof of identity, granting the user access to protected resources.

Any ideas how to achieve this with Warden on the server?

**Note**

I should mention that I'm leveraging `Rack::Session::Cookie` which I assume will be the unique token that is passed back and forth?